# Angular js + javascript heap size

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance

I am not sure whether this question is asked before or not. But I got a serious problem with my angular application and I haven't find proper solution for the same.

In my application, I have used Angular JS 1.0.8, smartTable component and jquery Qtip v2.2.1. I have 4 tabs which have shows tabular structure using smartTable component.

In smartTable, If we want to customize any cell data then we have to create directive to customize cell template.

As per my functionality, I have to show tooltip on over of cell data. I observed that jquery qtip data wasn't destroyed if we call destroy method. and If I call destroy method then after that it will give "Uncaught error: unable to call method show of null". I have try to disable the qtip for a while and I observed significant change in heap size increase rate. This is one issue.

Second issue: When I switch between tabs to show different tabular data. it increase heap size upto 12 to 15MB each time. So, how to reduce heap size increase rate?

To control heap size issue I have written destroy event in each controller and directive. in destroy event block I am assigning null values to string, make arrays blank

Is this the right approach?
What should be the way to write the proper controller and directive code?

Please provide your suggestions

Thanks,
Jay